# Trouble in equating a linear transformation $A$ to $A^{**}$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, dual-spaces, pullback

A pullback of a linear map $A:U\to V$ ($U,V$ are vector spaces) is $A^*:V^*\to U^*$ such that $A^*(f)(u)=f(A(u))$. I'm looking at a proof that $A^{**}=A$, which goes like this: For $u\in U$ and $g\in V^*$,
$$A^{**}(u)(g)=u(A^*(g))=A^*(g)(u)=g(A(u))=A(u)(g)$$
Since $v,g$ were arbitrary, $A^{**}=A$.

Clearly the second and last equalities have been written in that way because we naturally identify $U$ with its double dual and there's a natural equivalence between a vector and its double dual. **But that doesn't make them equal, right?** They are still *distinct objects* and using the same symbol for a vector and its double dual is to just reinforce the notion of their natural equivalence.

Explicitly writing the above series of equalities, we'll see something like:
$$A^{**}(u^{**})(g)=u^{**}(A^*(g))=A^*(g)(u)=g(A(u))=(A(u))^{**}(g)$$

So strictly speaking, shouldn't we conclude instead that $A^{**}(u^{**})=(A(u))^{**}$ for all $u\in U$? Seems that "$A^{**}=A$" is just the result of some notation trickery of removing the asterisks from the above equation.

Comment: Yes, you're right: the statement $A^{**}(u) = A(u)$ arises because each "double dual vector" $v^{**}$ is replaced with $v$. In particular, 
$A^{**}(u^{**}) = (A(u))^{**} \leadsto A^{**}(u) = A(u).$

Comment: Yes - in particular I conjecture this statement is not true in non-reflexive banach spaces.